# XMonad IndependantScreens does not load workspaces on second Screen at startup

Tags: haskell, window-managers, xmonad

I have setup IndependantScreens in XMonad so I can have per-monitor workspaces and it was going fine until I restarted my computer and now my second monitor by default opens on `0_code` (see code below to understand). Then if i move to my second monitor and switch to workspace `1` being `1_web` it then works.

Is there a way to fix this?

Code:

```
def {
        workspaces         = withScreens 2 [ "web", "code", "spare" ],
}
```

This might also be relevant.

```
myLayout = onWorkspaces [ "1_web","1_code","1_spare" ] myVerticalLayout $ myDefaultLayout
  where
    myDefaultLayout = tall
    myVerticalLayout = three
```

I checked that xrandr was setting the monitors correctly before xmonad launches and it is so I am not sure what is wrong.

Xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3640 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected 1080x1920+2560+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 544mm x 303mm
   1920x1080     60.00 + 164.92   144.00   119.98*   99.93    84.90    59.94    50.00  
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   2560x1440    144.00 + 119.99*   59.95
```

Comment: Funny. I suspect `withScreens` was written incorrectly, and I just never noticed. If you use ```workspaces = [marshall s vw | vw <- ["web", "code", "spare"], s <- [0, 1]]``` instead does it behave the way you expect? If so, `withScreens` should probably be fixed in xmonad-contrib. (As an aside, unrelated to your problem, your `onWorkspaces [...]` should probably be spelled `onWorkspaces (withScreen 1 ["web", "code", "spare"])`. This lets you share the list of virtual workspace names between your `workspaces` definition and its use here and protects you from changes to the marshalling format.)

Comment: That `marshall` line works perfectly thank you very much.
Do you know how i can change it so that each monitor has its own list of workspaces instead of sharing the same 3 names?

Comment: Err... I guess that depends a bit on your goals. If the two lists are disjoint, you don't need `IndependentScreens`, just name those workspaces and set up your keybindings appropriately, no?

Comment: I'm wanting a list of workspaces that only functions per screen so having one list of workspaces that functions accross screens is not what I am looking for.

I tried using two `withScreen` statements separating them with `$` but that returned errors.

Comment: Are there any names that could/should be available on both screens?

Comment: No, each set of work spaces should be isolated to their own screens not accessible on the other screen.

Comment: Then I repeat my previous assertion: you don't need `IndependentScreens`. Just name your workspaces, and set up your keybindings to only put workspaces on the appropriate screen.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Daniel Wagner this fixes the issue!

Replace

```
withScreens 2 ["web", "code", "spare"]
```

with

```
[marshall s vw | vw <- ["web", "code", "spare"], s <- [0, 1]]
```